# RecyclerView Adapter Methods not being called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView's Adapter's methods are not being called.

- Only `getItemCount()` and class Constructor are called (List is not
  empty, i have checked that).
- Methods `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` are not called.
- I have Other fragments in the same activity, using nearly same
  procedure but they are working perfectly fine.
- I tried creating a new Adapter class but that also didn't work.
- Method `getItemCount()` is called 2 times
- I am using same XML file for Adapter View for 2 different recyclerViews and they both are working fine.

My Adapter Class

```
public class OfflineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OfflineAdapter.OfflineHolder>{
private Context context;
private List<MovieDBObject> list;

public class OfflineHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.movie_grid_imageView)
    ImageView imageView;

    public OfflineHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        Log.i("bitmap", String.valueOf(4));
    }
}

public OfflineAdapter (Context context, List<MovieDBObject> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    Log.i("bitmap", String.valueOf(1));
}

@Override
public OfflineHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_grid_imageview, parent, false);
    Log.i("bitmap", String.valueOf(3));
    return new OfflineHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OfflineHolder holder, int position) {
    MovieDBObject object = list.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(object.getPoster());
    Log.i("bitmap", String.valueOf(5));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.i("bitmap", String.valueOf(2));
    return list.size();
}
}
```

Fragment Calling RecyclerView

```
public class FavouriteMovies extends Fragment{
@BindView(R.id.favourite_movies_recyclerView)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<MovieDBObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
MovieDBHelper movieDBHelper;
OfflineAdapter offlineAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fav_movies, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    movieDBHelper = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).dbHelper;
    final GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);

    offlineAdapter = new OfflineAdapter(getContext(), list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(offlineAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    prepareList();
    return rootView;
}

private void prepareList(){
    list = movieDBHelper.getAllMovies();
    Log.i("bitmap", list.size()+"");
    offlineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

XML File for the Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HELLO"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/favourite_movies_recyclerView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML File for the AdapterView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/movie_grid_imageView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OfflineAdapter` create a new method to set update data example:

```
private void updateData(List<MovieDBObject> dataList){
    this.list = dataList;
}
```

then update `prepareList`

```
private void prepareList(){
    list = movieDBHelper.getAllMovies();
    Log.i("bitmap", list.size()+"");
    offlineAdapter.updateData(list);
    offlineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your recyclerview is not hidden by the upper widget in the layout xml. For example, if there is a widget of height match_parent at the top of the recyclerview.