# Unable to bind RecyclerView using EventBus in android Tablets

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using Green Robot's EventBus for internal event messaging, I want to display data in my RecyclerView using EventBus. The problem is EventBus post message is received correctly and displays data on Android 5'' devices, but the **same code is not working on 7'' and 10'' tablets.** It works on all devices when the fragment loads first time, but when I try to bind data using EventBus it's not working.

```
   StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(colCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);

        SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(4);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(new ArrayList<Category>(), mListener);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
```

The above code block is in my onCreateView method.

```
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onClassificationEvent(final EventMessage event) {
    Log.e("onClassificationEvent", "onClassificationEvent AllFragment :" + event.getEventId());

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (event.getEventId() == "20") {
                //All
                bindCategories(3);
            } else if (event.getEventId() == "21") {
                //Veg
                bindCategories(1);
            } else if (event.getEventId() == "22") {
                //NonVeg
                bindCategories(2);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

The above code is my EventBus subscribed method

```
 private void bindCategories(final int classification) {

    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    if (classification == 1) {
        categories = DbAccessHelper.CategoriesHelper.getVegCategories(getActivity());
    } else if (classification == 2) {
        categories = DbAccessHelper.CategoriesHelper.getNonVegCategories(getActivity());
    } else if (classification == 3) {
        categories = DbAccessHelper.CategoriesHelper.getAllCategories(getActivity());
    }
    if (categories != null) {
        if (!categories.isEmpty()) {
            tvError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categories, mListener);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
            categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            tvError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(new ArrayList<Category>(), mListener);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        }
    } else {
        tvError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(new ArrayList<Category>(), mListener);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    }


}
```

This method is used to bind RecyclerView with data. Can someone help me find the issue?

Comment: Are you getting any Exception?

Comment: no exceptions, I checked my Logs, only getItemCount() gets called in my adapter, onBindViewHolder is not getting called

Comment: does this have anything to do with Threading? someone plz help me

Comment: Are you sure your flow is going `if (!categories.isEmpty())`? Try debugging.

Comment: yes it is going inside that block, this code is working perfectly in 5 inch mobile devices, the problem is in 7 and 10 inch tablets

Comment: May be in tablet your code is going to next `if()` in that the recyclerview's visibility GONE.

Comment: no I already checked that. I don't know why the same code is behaving differently on different type of devices.

Comment: Finally I found the solution [from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38214333/7267250)